# Update textview inside Bind method after callback result RecylerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I am working on the Twilio Chat application and wanted to append the last message on each room call back result is a bit delay so my recycler view getting drawn.

**What I need:**
Wants to update the last message text once call back result, though I have used `adapter.notifyItemChanges(positon)` but it updates every time and getting n number of the result's from the callback (Don't know why it been called more than 10 times each time) and it generates ANR due to heavy work. Below is my bind code:

```
class ChatThreadVH(
private val binding: SingleMessageThreadItemBinding,
private val adapter: ChatThreadAdapter,
private val channel: Channels) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

fun bind(chatThread: Data, position: Int) {
    binding.source = chatThread
    binding.position = position
    binding.adapter = adapter
    getLastMessage(channel, position, binding.source!!)
}


private fun getLastMessage(channel: Channels, position: Int, source: Data) {

    channel.getChannel(
        source.remoteChannelId,
        ChatCallbackListener<Channel> { channel ->
            channel.messages?.getLastMessages(1, ChatCallbackListener<List<Message>> {
                if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
                    if (it[0].hasMedia()) {
                        binding.tvLastMessage.text = "attachment"
                    } else {
                        binding.tvLastMessage.text = it[0].messageBody
                    }
                }
            })
        })
}
```

}

So Any help on this highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you calling `adapter.notifyItemChanges(positon)`  in `onChannelUpdated(Channel channel, Channel.UpdateReason updateReason)` callback? if yes check if `updateReason == LAST_MESSAGE` to prevent multiple calls

Comment: @MkhitarHakobyan how can i update the adapter after call back result?

Comment: simply invoke `adapter.notifyItemChanges(positon)`

Answer (score 0):

```
YourViewModelClass() : ViewModel(), ChatClientListener {
   
   private lateinit var channels: MutableList<Channel>
   val notifyChannelUpdated = MutableLiveData<Int>()

   override fun onChannelUpdated(channel: Channel, p1: Channel.UpdateReason) {
       if(p1 == Channel.UpdateReason.LAST_MESSAGE) {
           val channelPos = channels.indexOfFirst { it.id == channel.id }
           notifyChannelUpdated.postValue(channelPos)
       }
   }
}


Then update your item, becouse there are many reasons why channel may update


class YourActivityOrFragmentClass() : SomeAndroidComponentClass() {
       private lateinit var myAdapter: SomeAdapter
       private lateinit var myViewModel: YourViewModelClass

        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            myViewModel.notifyChannelUpdated.observe(viewLifcycleOwner, { position ->
               myAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
            })
        }
   }
```

Comment: there is no such method Channel.UpdateReason in Channel class of twilio

Comment: [`UpdateReason` is an enum of the `Channel` class](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/chat/releases/6.2.0/docs/enumcom_1_1twilio_1_1chat_1_1Channel_1_1UpdateReason.html).